# Multiple Certificates In Single Keystore & One Tomcat Instance

Tags: java, tomcat, keystore

I'm working on a project in Java and having an issue authenticating to a merchant service for credit card transactions.

Currently I have a single tomcat instance that runs, and a single keystore that contains multiple certificates. We can get our web service to work with a single certificate connecting to the 3rd party merchant service. The issue is that we're trying to utilize a couple dozen certificates because the merchant service issues a unique cert per customer.

So the question I have: is it possible to configure tomcat in such a way that I can dynamically specify which certificate to use from the keystore on a per-connection basis?

Comment: The question is not clear.How does Tomcat fit in the picture?Are you trying to do client authentication against a Tomcat server?

Comment: So a little background. We have a java service running in tomcat. What we're trying to do is establish a web service connection from our java service to a 3rd party merchant service API. The merchant service requires a unique certificate used for each customer we're doing transactions for. The problem is we can configure tomcat to use the cert for CustomerA, but we don't know how to tell tomcat that the next connection for CustomerB will use a different certificate. Does that make it more clear? Tomcat is handling the authentication to the 3rd party, but appears to only expect to handle 1 cert

Comment: No it is not clear.Tomcat is a server.Do you have some module deployed in Tomcat that acts as a client to the 3rd party web service? In this case, Tomcat's https connectors are not involved.So may be you should give a little more explanation on this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your problem correctly. But one way of handling multiple certificates in a single keystore is to use alias in the Key/Trust Managers.